# И мясо(,) и морковку я ем

Tags: запятые, и

Нужны запятые?

`Я ем и рыбу(,) и мясо.`

`Я ем и рыбу(,) и овощи.`

`И мясо(,) и морковку я ем.`

Comment: все через запятую с вероятностью в 99.5% скучное задание.

Comment: Без КОНТЕКСТА задачу бесполезно решать: ни правила, ни примеры не помогут.  Можно и не стараться А так – твори, выдумывай, пробуй!  Хотите попробовать?))  Можно в стихах, мне понравилось ваше творчество)  Что-то в нем есть...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в контексте подразумевается **тесная связь** однородных членов, то запятой нет. Если же они рассматриваются **отдельно,** то запятая ставится.

**Вариант 1**

*Я ем **и рЫбу, и мЯсо**, чего я только не ем.*

*Я ем **и рыбу и мЯсо**, это же белки!*

**Вариант 2**

*Я ем **и рыбу и овОщи**, так что рыба с овощами мне подойдет.*

*Я ем **и рЫбу, и Овощи**. Полезные продукты!*

**Вариант 3**

*Все полезно: мясо и морковка.  **И мясо и моркОвку** я ем.*

*Мясо или морковка? Я не выбираю. **И мЯсо, и моркОвку** я ем.*

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь ([Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101)):

> **2.** При двух однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом ***и***, запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов): *Кругом было **и светло и зелено*** (Т.); *Он носил **и лето и зиму** старую жокейскую кепку* (Пауст.); *Прибрежная полоса, пересечённая мысами, уходила **и в ту и в другую сторону*** (Сем.); *Он был **и весел и печален** в одно и то же время*.
> Такие смысловые единства образуются словами с ассоциативными (часто антонимическими) связями...

Во всех предложениях запятая ставится:
*Я ем и рыбу, и мясо. Я ем и рыбу, и овощи. И мясо, и морковку я ем.*

Сомнения могло вызвать, собственно, только первое предложение — похожестью на неразложимое сочетание ***ни рыба ни мясо***.

*Нет, мы едим — и Машка ест — **и мясо, и рыбу*** (А. И. Пантелеев. Наша Маша).

*Мол, ты сам только своей работой живешь, ничего тебя в жизни не интересует, хоть бы ты по бабам шлялся, так хоть на нормального мужика был бы похож, а так – **ни рыба ни мясо**...* (Александра Маринина. Шестерки умирают первыми).

Comment: Но *и рыбу, и мясо* — это же образует то, про что талдычит Розенталь!